# How to close all TinyMCE Inline Editors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE 4 in it's inline mode. However I am at a loss as to how to programmaticaly close the windows during certain other operation on the page. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In tinymce3 this worked (and i guess this should work in tinymce4 too):

```
for (var i=tinymce.editors.length; i>=0; i--) {
  tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',false, tinymce.editors[i].id); 
};
```